# Exception "evaluating textInputRef.isFocuded" when iOS SignIn modal is open, react native in app purchases

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native, in-app-purchase

i'm getting this error when I click in a product returned from apple.
This error is only the first time in that i make click, after, all work fine.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You're probably trying to reach ref's isFocused prop before its initialized. Add a null check and you should be fine.

```
textInputRef?.isFocused
```

Comment: But, the modal come from react native ios, idk where i can get the file to fix it